# Java: Printing for each number in array frequency of occurrence in percent

Tags: java, arrays, frequency

For homework I have to print for each integer in an array frequency of occurrence. This would mean that if I have for example an array with integers 1,2,2,5 the program would print:

```
Number 1: 25%
Number 2: 50%
Number 5: 25%
```

Or for example array with numbers 1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3 it would print:

```
Number 1: 25%
Number 2: 33.33333%
Number 3: 41.66666%
```

We've been learning for loops and if structures so I would like to do it this way all in one class and in "public static void main(String[] args) {} function.

Anyone can give me some advices how do I even start this?
I don't need a solution just advices how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't show any effort to solve this by your own, it will be hard to find somebody to write the code for you.

Comment: Did I ask for the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can do with rule of three:
>
> Example: 1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3
>
> You have 12 numbers.
>
> Number 1: 3,
>
> Number 2: 4,
>
> Number 3: 5
>
> ---
>
> 12 - 100%
>
> 03 - X
>
> ---
>
> Number 1 porcent: 12x = 100 * 3 = 25%
>
> Number 2 porcent: 12x = 100 * 4 = 25%
>
> Number 3 porcent: 12x = 100 * 5 = 25%
>
> Number X porcent: Total * x = 100 * Quantity = Porcent in %
>
> I think it works

Answer (score 1):

You know how many numbers you have, such as in your first example, you have 4 numbers.
You know "2" appears in it twice. So, 2/4 = 0.5 and 0.5*100 = 50%
The same works for the "1". It appears once, so 1/4 = 0.25 and 0.25*100 = 25%.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this exercise is that you use

> String.split(exp)

, somethink like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String numbers = "1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3";
        String[] arrayNumbers = numbers.split(",");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayNumbers.length ; i++){
             //count each number and divide by arrayNumbers.length
        }
 }
```